# Is QGIS compatible with Windows 11?

Tags: qgis, windows

My workplace is moving to Windows 11 and want to check whether current software is fully compatible. I have been asked for some confirming documentation that QGIS is Windows 11 compatible, but can only find reference to Windows (no version stated). I've looked through the online docs, this forum, Reddit etc... and there does not seem to be any problem with QGIS on Windows 11 but I also can't find a authoritative statement that it is compatible.

Can anyone help?

Comment: QGIS is built with QT 5.15 which lists Windows 11 as a supported platform. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/supported-platforms.html

Answer (score 4):

QGIS 3.34 LTR (current) is fully compatible with Windows 11 as far as I know. At the very least, I didn't experience any problems so far. QGIS homepage apparently doesn't state it explicitly, so here's a screenshot as empirical evidence:

[image: Screenshot]